# AppCode won't highlight errors

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I'm trying out AppCode for a simple Swift iOS application, and the first thing I noticed is it won't highlight any error whatsoever. The build fails with simple errors like `use of unresolved identifier 'param'`, but it won't highlight to let me know said variable doesn't exist. Moreover, the the file analysis (little green checkmark at top-right corner) says `No problem found`.

I'm using **AppCode 2016.1**

Do I have to make some kind of extra configuration or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Showing warnings and errors in editor is not yet implemented in AppCode 2016.1 for Swift. This feature is ready in AppCode 2016.2 Early Access Preview. Download it [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/OBJC/AppCode+EAP) and in case you interested in updates - read about it in our [blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/)

Comment: They mostly don't work for me, even on 2018.RC1. Here are two examples: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmvv7lib4h57poq/some_show.png?dl=0 | https://www.dropbox.com/s/klaaoxe7mugpozl/most_do_not.png?dl=0. There's even a green checkbox top-right 